# CSS3: Overlaying a gradient image over a DIV

Tags: css, overlay

I have [this image](http://i50.tinypic.com/2m2b9td.png) which I want to use over div of ANY color to give a glossy look. What should I do? should I use it as a background or add it on other div and put it on previous one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.your_div {
    background: #f39 url(http://i50.tinypic.com/2m2b9td.png) no-repeat left bottom;
}
```